# non-homogeneous boundary value prblem - help!

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, heat-equation

I am studying boundary value problems and I have worked out the partial derivatives and worked out my $V*$ and its constants.

Now I have a heat equation to solve using $X(x)T(t)$. Using the auxiliary equation 
$X''(x)+k^2X(x)=0$ and subbing in my boundary conditions I know that $A=0$.

However for working out $B$ I am stuck as the second condition is $u(1,t)=100$.

How do I solve $B \sin k=100$?

Answer (score 0):

When considering linear boundary value problems, you should apply the superposition principle in order to forget about non-homogenous boundary conditions. I guess your problem is something like:

$$u_t = u_{xx}, \quad 0 < x < 1, \quad t > 0,$$

with boundary and inital conditions:

$$u(0,t) = 0, \quad u(1,t) = 100, \quad t > 0; \quad u(x,0) = f(x), \quad x \in [0,1]$$

for some known function $f(x)$. Make now the substitution $u = v+w$, such that $v$ satisfies homogenous boundary conditions and $w$ "absorbe" them, so the *sum* of the two problems always leads to the original one. Assume $w(x,t) = A(t) x + B(t)$ and note that, for example, $w(x,t) = 100 \, x$ is a very good solution which satisfies the non-homogenous boundary conditions. Then, the problem for $v$ becomes:

$$v_t = v_{xx} - w_t + w_{xx} = v_{xx}, \quad 0 < x < 1, \quad t > 0,$$

with boundary and inital conditions:

$$v(0,t) = 0, \quad v(1,t) = 0, \quad t > 0; \quad v(x,0) = f_0(x)-w(x,0), \quad x \in [0,1],$$  and note that everything containing information from $w$ is **known**. Now the problem is to determine the function $v$, which satisfies an **homogneous** second order PDE (heat equation) subject to *homogneous* boundary conditions. We can now apply separation of variables (or Sturm-Liouville theory if you prefer so) to the PDE for $v$, assuming:

$$v(x,t) = X(x)T(t), \quad T \neq 0 \neq X, $$

which yields to the set of equations that you have already come up to before, i.e.:

$$\begin{align}
X'' - \lambda X & = 0,\\
T' - \lambda T & = 0,
\end{align}
$$ where $\lambda$ is a constant, which can be negative, zero or positive. Apply the boundary conditions for $X$, which result to be: $X(0)=X(1)=0$ to solve the problem for $X$ (you don't need to solve after for $T$). This only makes sense for negative values of $\lambda$, so $\lambda = - |\lambda| = - k^2$ and it yields:

$$X(x) = A \cos k x + B \sin kx, $$

applying the aforementioned boundary conditions, we have: $A = 0$ and:

$$B \sin k = 0,$$

which is true if $B = 0$ (not valid) or $\sin kx = 0$ which happens to be if $k$ is a natural multiple of $\pi$, so:

$$k = n \pi, \quad n = 1,2,3,\ldots \equiv \mathbb{N},$$

so the solutions for every $n$ are:

$$X_n(x) = B_n \sin k_n x = \sin n\pi x,$$

where I have set $B_n \to 1$ due to the "homogenous-ness" of the equation for $X$. This functions are called **eigenfunctions** of the problem and you can obtain the solution $v$ by expanding it as follows:

$$v(x,t) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty X_n(x) C_n(t),$$

and solving for the Fourier coefficients, $C_n(t)$. I'm sure you can take it from here.

I hope this might help you.

Cheers!